# Pytest - Create test result for every assert in dynamically created outputs in loop

Tags: python, pytest, assert

I have exaple function:

```
def test_foo(arg1, arg2):
    for i in len(arg1):
        output_1 = i+1
        output_2 = arg2[0] + i
        assert output_1 == output2
```

In this case I get only one output from test: Pass if all aserts pass or Fail if any assert fails? How to expand this code to get separate test result form every time assert is called? I tried with creating test generator, but pytest in version > 4.0 is not supporitng yield tests anymore. I have no idea how to properly use @pytest.mark.parametrize, most of examples uses predefined variables as expected result while I'm creating them dynamically in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a `try except` to catch the Assertion Error, where you can do any other code:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    try:
        assert #whatever
    except AssertionError:
         #assert code
```

Comment: But still, I will not have separete test for every assert call right? That's what I care most about in this issue

Comment: I edited the code. Now if there is an assert, it will be caught and you can do whatever you want. @wolfek

Comment: Thanks, it will catch assertionerror, but stil in console output I will have one result from "main" test. I thought there will be possibility to use @pytest.mark.parametrize to use it like yield test generator somehow...

Comment: If you are having this much trouble with asserts, I think it wise of you to use an if else statement instead. @wolfek

Comment: Yes, this will be much easier, but in tihs case I must stick to the pytest and assert convention... It looks like that I must leave assert in loop and get one, general test reslt.